# Insert Unicode string using odata client library for windows phone

Tags: sql, azure, unicode, windows-phone, odata

I am using Odata client library for windows phone to access my azure sql tables. One problem that I had is to insert Unicode string. When I use sql server management studio, I put a N before that unicode string in the insert query, the string will show up in the db correctly. However, how can I achieve the same using odata client library programmatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Odata entity properties have a boolean attribute called "Unicode".  Make sure it's set to true on the model you're using on the phone for the entity property you're setting, and that the $metadata url of the odata service you're accessing shows the the same entity property setting the unicode attribute to true.